# Removing rectangular div around the 3D Pie chart drawn using Highchart.js

Tags: angularjs, charts, highcharts, 3d

I am drawing a 3D pie chart using highchart.js. Please find the below code

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 150,
            beta: 0
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            depth: 35,

        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Browser share',
        data: [
            [ 45.0],

            {

                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }

        ]
    }]
});
```

With the above code 3D pie chart with a whitecolore rectangular background is displayed as follows
[image]

Can I get only the circular part without having the rectangular part ?

Comment: I'm not getting the line https://jsfiddle.net/Ladm7cfg/ provide actual code you use

Comment: Could you reproduce your chart in an online code editor? Your code doesn't show the rectangular. Check the demo posted by @PandiyanCool